# Greatest common divisor with noise

Tags: python, excel, numpy, scipy

I have a set of data like below. The numbers are integral multiples of an unkown value X. For ex: 1466 = N*X, but there is noise in both the N and X, so N may not be a perfect integer.  If I sort and plot the data, it looks like a step sequence with some steps missing (in a larger data set). Any idea how to solve this?

1466
4466
5671
6131
6246
7123

Comment: Probably better-suited for http://stats.stackexchange.com.  FWIW, if there were no steps missing, then linear regression would be a viable approach.

Comment: Do you know when a step is missing/ the corresponding step to each value? @SEU

Comment: Can you share a larger data set?